# find first checkbox in a row : not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find the first check box in a row, each time it checks the first check box in the table instead, here is the table and the code inside the docready

```
$('.otherMoneyToo').blur(function() {
    thisSelector = $('tr td:first-child input').attr('name');

    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $("input[name='" + thisSelector + "']").prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        var myTransAmount = $(this).val();
        $('.otherMoney').prop('checked', false);
        $('.otherMoneyToo').val('');
        $(this).val(myTransAmount);

        $("input[name='" + thisSelector + "']").prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

HTML :

```
<table class='drkblue   moneyTransfer' align='center'>
    <tr class='main'>
        <td colspan='4'>
            <hr>Transfer money:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='main'>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' class='otherMoney' name='omcb00000006040000'>0000000604:SAVINGS/SHARE ACCT</td>
        <td>2,161.50</td>
        <td>Amount: </td>
        <td>
            <input name='omTrans00000006040000' class='money otherMoneyToo'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='main'>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' class='otherMoney' name='omcb00000006040090'>0000000604:CHECKING/DRAFT ACCT</td>
        <td>677.03</td>
        <td>Amount: </td>
        <td>
            <input name='omTrans00000006040090' class='money otherMoneyToo'>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle..

Comment: the problem is with `thisSelector=$('tr td:first-child input').attr('name');`  It points to `tr`, without an id or class in front of the `tr`.  jQuery will stop when it reaches the first match, which is the first `tr` in the table.

Comment: Are you wanting to select `each` first checkbox, of every row, or a specific checkbox based upon an action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably not maintaining the context of the blur. You want to keep the changes within the row where the blur happened. Thus,

```
thisSelector=$('tr td:first-child input').attr('name');
```

Should be:

```
var thisSelector = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').attr('name');
```

```js
    $('.otherMoneyToo').blur(function(){   
        thisSelector= $(this).closest('tr').find('input').attr('name');

        if ($(this).val()=='') {
            $("input[name='"+thisSelector+"']").prop('checked',false);
        } else {
            var myTransAmount=$(this).val();
            $('.otherMoney').prop('checked',false);
            $('.otherMoneyToo').val('');
            $(this).val(myTransAmount);

            $("input[name='"+thisSelector+"']").prop('checked',true);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='drkblue   moneyTransfer' align='center' >
<tr class='main'><td colspan='4'><hr>Transfer money:</td></tr>
  <tr class='main'>
<td><input type='checkbox' class='otherMoney' 
name='omcb00000006040000' >0000000604:SAVINGS/SHARE ACCT</td>
<td>2,161.50</td> 
<td>Amount:  </td>
<td><input name='omTrans00000006040000' class='money otherMoneyToo'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='main'>
<td><input type='checkbox' class='otherMoney' 
name='omcb00000006040090' >0000000604:CHECKING/DRAFT ACCT</td>
<td>677.03</td> 
<td>Amount:  </td>
<td><input name='omTrans00000006040090' class='money otherMoneyToo'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you, I was trying to get the closest to work but wasn't sure of the context, it is working now... after a bit you know your brain turns to much :)

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Please feel free to upvote and accept the answer. Enjoy!